# Parental Controls with FaceTime app does not work properly on iPad Air

Tags: ipad, facetime, parental-controls

We have a problem about the FaceTime app and Parental Controls on our iPad Air.

Even after we disabled the FaceTime app by Parental Controls, our iPad Air(Wi-Fi model) tries to connect to the FaceTime server (init.ess.apple.com).

We see a lot of the same kind of packets going out to the Internet and our firewall drops them although we use our iPad Air only for internal services in our LAN.

Apple technical support said that iPad Air should not try to connect to the FaceTime server with the FaceTime app disabled by Parent Control.

Could you please let us know if you have any idea about this issue or have the same problem?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This domain(*.ess.apple.com ) is not only work for FaceTime, but also service many service of Apple, such as iMessage, the authentication, administration, key and contract request runs over https.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into the possibility that other applications or services send the packets.